# My python 3.4 button won't count the number of times it's clicked

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I run python 3.4, and I know some stuff about programing but i can't make my program count the number of times the user clicks on the button. Here is what i tried.

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
    counter = 0
def mbutton():
  def count():
    global counter
    counter +=1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='button', command=mbutton).pack()
root.mainloop
```

I hit the button and then it keeps counting, so tried different combonations of the equal and plus sign.

example 1:

```
counter =+1
```

example 2:

```
counter +1
```

That's all I could think of and reserch helped a little bit with my placing of my code, but thank you for your help. Sorry if there are any grammar errors.

Comment: Why are you calling doing the `after` to call `count` again from inside `count`?  That means `count` will just keep calling itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't what you think it is. Currently, you're operating under the assumption that you're not correctly adding together numbers in your code. In reality, your code just isn't running at all.

Specifically, in your last line of code, you do `root.mainloop`. However, `mainloop` is a function so in order to call it, you need to do `root.mainloop()`. Doing `root.mainloop` is a statement -- you're telling Python "here is a function" -- Python won't do anything. It *does* build up the GUI, and wires everything together, but never actually starts running and displaying the GUI. When you do `root.mainloop()`, you actually *call* the function and execute it, making use of everything you just wrote.

So, you now have the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
    counter = 0
def mbutton():
  def count():
    global counter
    counter +=1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='button', command=mbutton).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However, when you try and run this, you'll run into another problem -- clicking the button doesn't increment the counter just once, but causes rapidly start increasing.

The problem is with the line `label.after(1000, count)`. What this is doing is telling your label "hey, after 1000 milliseconds, automatically run the `count` function again. When you run the `count` function again, it'll run into that line and try and run the `count` function again after another 1000 milliseconds, etc...

It loops forever.

Instead, get rid of that line (and get rid of the unnecessary `count` function):

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0 

def counter_label(label):
    counter = 0

def mbutton():
    global counter
    counter +=1
    label.config(text=str(counter))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='button', command=mbutton).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

One final problem is that `counter_label` isn't actually doing anything. It accepts a label as a parameter, but doesn't actually do anything with it. It also sets the counter to zero, but since you never declared `counter` to be global, it never actually modifies the global counter. In any case, your counter is already zero, so there's no point in setting it to zero again.

We can omit it entirely. Also, `mbutton` isn't a very descriptive name for a function -- it might be better to rename it into something more descriptive of the action that will be carried out:

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0 

def increment_counter():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")

label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='button', command=increment_counter).pack()

root.mainloop()
```